# Angular Service "undefined" after first run

Tags: angularjs

So my readingController calls getRomanization in the main body the first time and it in turn calls the Romanize factory service (shown below controller). This all works fine the fist time but the second time when round when getRomanization is called at the end of checkRomanization the Romanize service comes up as `undefined` in Chrome. What happens to the Romanize service? why does it only run successfully once?

Please help me with this as I have been stuck for ages.

```
var readingController = function ($scope, Romanize){
    $scope.getRomanization = function(Romanize){
        $scope.currentMaterial = $scope.sections[$scope.sectionNumber].tutorials[$scope.tutorialNumber].material[$scope.questionNumber];
        Romanize.get($scope.currentMaterial).then(function(d){
            $scope.romanized = d;
        });

        $scope.$apply();
    };
    $scope.getRomanization(Romanize);
    $scope.$apply();
    $scope.checkRomanization = function(userRomanization){
        if ($scope.romanized === userRomanization){
            $scope.questionNumber++;
            $scope.getRomanization();
        };
    }
}

app.factory('Romanize', ['$http', 'Position', function($http, Position){
    return{
      get: function(query){
            var url= Position.sections[Position.sectionNumber].romanizeService + "?korean=" + query;
            var promise = $http.get(url).then(function(d) {
                var parts = $(d.data).find("span");
                var array = [];
                for (var x = 0; x<parts.length; x++){
                    array.push(parts[x].title);
                }
                var result = array.join("");
                return result;
            });
            return promise;
        }
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second call to getRomanize is missing the service name as an argument

```
$scope.checkRomanization = function(userRomanization){
    if ($scope.romanized === userRomanization){
        $scope.questionNumber++;
        $scope.getRomanization(Romanize);
    };
};
```

Comment: Thankyou so much Chris, I can't believe I missed something so simple!

Comment: It happens to all of us after a couple of hours ;}